# when i get an index of a vector in c++, it always returns last value that is push backed

Tags: c++, random, vector, indexing, push-back

I create a global vector. After that I add values with push_back function. But, when I want to get an arbitrary index of vector, it always returns the last value that was pushed. The code is the following:

```
struct Choromosome{
    float fitness;
    float selectionProb;
    bool isSelected;
    int conflictNum;
    int* geneCode;
};
int SIZE = 6;
int START_SIZE = 50;
vector<Choromosome> population;

void initialize(){
  for(int k = 0; k < START_SIZE; k++){
     Choromosome c;
     int* code = new int[SIZE];
     srand(time(NULL));
     for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        code[i] = rand() % SIZE;
     }
     c.geneCode = code;
     population.push_back(c);
  }
  int rand1 = rand() % START_SIZE;
  int rand2 = rand() % START_SIZE;     
  std::ostream_iterator< int > output( cout, " " );
  std::copy( population[rand1].geneCode, population[rand1].geneCode+ SIZE, output );
  std::copy( population[rand2].geneCode, population[rand2].geneCode+ SIZE, output );
}
```

Comment: Based on your description it definitely sounds like a pointer logic error.

Comment: Any reason for not using a vector for `geneCode`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are seeding with `srand(time(NULL));` every iteration.

If you check the generated numbers, you'll see they are the same for every `Chromosome`.

You either have to take out of the `for` that `srand()` or give it a current time parameter.

Comment: Thank you, this solve this problem. Hovewer when i call two indexes of the population from another function, it still returns the last index, although i don't use rand.